# How to create Vertical Bar Chart with Kendo Angular?

Tags: charts, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to create a vertical bar chart with Kendo Angular Components but I couldn't find any example or configuration in the documentation.

Here is the link to the charts documentation: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/

There is a bar chart in there that shows horizontal bars, but I need vertical bars.

**PROBLEM:**

I need to create vertical bar chart with Kendo Angular Components.

Answer (score 5):

**To create vertical bar chart:**

The configuration is exactly the same, with the only difference being setting the series type to "column" instead of "bar".

**Here are some runnable samples:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzzqer?file=app/app.component.ts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wme4dg?file=app/app.component.ts